# Wrap Content of ItemsControls

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I am using two different ItemsControl to generate a list of Buttons.

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding}">
                <!-- ... -->
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTransaction.Modifiers}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}">
                <!-- ... -->   
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</WrapPanel>
```

The buttons of the 2nd ItemsControl appear on a new "Line"

[image]

Is it possible that the Buttons of the 2nd ItemsControl appear directly after the Buttons from the first ItemsControl? The number of Buttons may vary. It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: How about merging the two item collections into one and having only one ItemsControl with an [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) that returns the appropriate DataTemplate for each item.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I merged the two lists and now I'm using implicit DataTemplates. Works great. I'll accept your answer, but you have to post it as an "answer" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge the two item collections into one and have only one ItemsControl with an [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) that returns the appropriate DataTemplate for each item.